# Adjust table with images in every row inside a div

Tags: html, css, html-table, grid-layout

I have defined a layout which has many elements. One of these element is a grey box (a div) in which I place a table. That table has rows and it contains small images.

What I want to achieve is to adjust the table inside it parents. I want the images to be loaded automatically depending on how many they are (quantity of images is variable)... so when reaching the grey box max size the line should break and send the images to the next row. Is this possible?

Furthermore I try to make it resizable to different screen sizes.

Here Css and Html snippet:

```css
body {
   background-color:  #141414;
   margin-top:3%;
   margin-left: 2%;
   margin-right: 2%;
}


.video-item {
   width: 30%; 
   float: left; 
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.video-item-2 {
   width: 66%; 
   float: left; 
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.video-display {
   background-color: #1F1F1F; 
   height: 450px;
}

p {
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

#thumbs {
   word-wrap: break-word; 
   table-layout:fixed;
   width: 100%;
}

#thumbnail-grid {
   background-color: #1F1F1F; 
   height: 450px;

}

.video-spacer {
   width: 2%;
   float: left;
   min-height: 200px;
}

#arrow_up, #arrow_down {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#arrow_down {
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="video-item">
  <p class="font-semibold">Something else</p>         
  <div class="video-display"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="video-spacer"></div>

<div class="video-item-2">
    <p class="font-semibold">THUMBNAIL PREVIEW</p>
      <div id="thumbnail-grid">
        <img id="arrow_up" src='http://www.pngdot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Png_Up_Arrow_01.png' alt="arrow" height="25" width="45">
          <table id="thumbs">
             <tr>
                  <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td>
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td>
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td>
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td>
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td>
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td> 
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td> 
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td>
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td> 
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td> 
               <td tabindex="3"><img id="arrow_up" src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60"></td> 
               </tr>
           </table>
           <img id="arrow_down" src='http://www.pngdot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Png_Up_Arrow_01.png' alt="arrow" height="25" width="45">
         </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I would like to solve this with css only but if js or jquery is necessary, then I accept it.

Thanks!

Comment: I see only one row in the demo and I only see one row in the code...when you said, "rows" did you mean "cells" or "columns"?

Comment: Do you want to always show one row of images per time, with the top/bottom arrow to scroll for more?

Comment: @zer00ne I wrote just one row on the demo so the images that overflows the box goes to the next one. I meant row, horizontally

Comment: @Pangloss exactly, once the images reachs the grey box's capacity, in width and height

Comment: OK, you need to work on the wodpress query part, so only output a number of images you want, let's say 10, so one <tr> with 10 <td> and image in each.

Comment: @Pangloss is this solution ok for other width's screens?

Comment: Just need some style on the img tag, check out this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wd3g52rc/) resize and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which, when reaches the width, break into new lines.

```css
body {
   background-color:  #141414;
   margin-top:3%;
   margin-left: 2%;
   margin-right: 2%;
}


.video-item {
   width: 30%; 
   float: left; 
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.video-item-2 {
   width: 66%; 
   float: left; 
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.video-display {
   background-color: #1F1F1F; 
   height: 450px;
}

p {
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

#thumbs {
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#thumbnail-grid {
   background-color: #1F1F1F; 
   height: 450px;
}

.video-spacer {
   width: 2%;
   float: left;
   min-height: 200px;
}

#arrow_up, #arrow_down {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#arrow_down {
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="video-item">
  <p class="font-semibold">Something else</p>         
  <div class="video-display"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="video-spacer"></div>

<div class="video-item-2">
    <p class="font-semibold">THUMBNAIL PREVIEW</p>
      <div id="thumbnail-grid">
        <img id="arrow_up" src='http://www.pngdot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Png_Up_Arrow_01.png' alt="arrow" height="25" width="45">
        
          <div id="thumbs">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">

            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">

            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">

            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">
            <img src='http://oleaass.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Random-truths18.jpg' alt="arrow" height="40" width="60">

          </div>
        <img id="arrow_down" src='http://www.pngdot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Png_Up_Arrow_01.png' alt="arrow" height="25" width="45">
      </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: how can I center the images inside the grey box? it appears with a little margin on the right

Comment: @Limon Updated my answer. Added this: `#thumbs { text-align: center; }`

Comment: pretty good! only 2 things... 1). when I resize the page having the full box loaded with images, it gets messy and the images flow out of the box. 2). is your solution valid for big screens?

Comment: @Limon 1. To overcome the "flow out of the box" is to either set the `#thumbnail-grid {min-height: 450px;}` so it resize itself, or make `#thumbs` scroll. Updated my answer with scroll sample  .... 2. My solution works on any screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Use "div" instead of table. When you use **td** tag, every cell is in the same row when using it in a single **tr** row. HTML:

```
<div id="tableContent">
    <img class="singleImage" ...... / >
</div>
```

and the CSS (use "float"):

```
.singleImage {
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
}
```